# WooCommerce remove specific attribute values from shop filter

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have two color values (from a product attribute) which are necessary for product variations but should be excluded from product filters. Can I remove these 2 color values via PHP in the functions.php? The two values should ONLY be removed from the filters, but not anywhere else.

The two values from the color attribute ("Farbe" = color) are "weiß/rot" and "weiß/blau".

Product filters: http://wordpress.p585884.webspaceconfig.de/shop/

The HTML:

```
<ul class="woocommerce-widget-layered-nav-list">
<li class="woocommerce-widget-layered-nav-list__item wc-layered-nav-term "><a class="awb-woo-attr" rel="nofollow" href="http://wordpress.p585884.webspaceconfig.de/shop/?filter_farbe=weiss-rot"><span class="awb-woo-attr-wrapper"><span class="avada-color-select"><span style="background-color: #862238"></span></span><span class="awb-woo-attr-name">weiß/rot</span></span><span class="awb-woo-attr-count">(1)</span></a></li>
<li class="woocommerce-widget-layered-nav-list__item wc-layered-nav-term "><a class="awb-woo-attr" rel="nofollow" href="http://wordpress.p585884.webspaceconfig.de/shop/?filter_farbe=weiss-blau"><span class="awb-woo-attr-wrapper"><span class="avada-color-select"><span style="background-color: #4d5f74"></span></span><span class="awb-woo-attr-name">weiß/blau</span></span><span class="awb-woo-attr-count">(1)</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Screenshot of "Products / Attributes":
[image]

This jQuery solution I put together works, but I'd prefer to remove the unnecessary code before the page loads with PHP.

```
$('.woocommerce-widget-layered-nav-list__item .awb-woo-attr-name:contains("weiß/rot")').parents().eq(2).remove();
$('.woocommerce-widget-layered-nav-list__item .awb-woo-attr-name:contains("weiß/blau")').parents().eq(2).remove();
```

In case a PHP solution is not possible. How can I add these lines together? I've tried a "," in between without success.

Comment: Attribute wont be added if there are no products with this attribute. There is this filter woocommerce_layered_nav_term_html which you can use and ignore terms.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following jQuery code to combine the selectors

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.woocommerce-widget-layered-nav-list__item .awb-woo-attr-name:contains("weiß/rot"), .woocommerce-widget-layered-nav-list__item .awb-woo-attr-name:contains("weiß/blau")').parents().eq(2).remove();
});
```

Comment: I've tried this (and a similar approach before), but it ends up only removing the "weiß/blau" but not the "weiß/rot".